# Odoo. How to completely disable developer mode on production server?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to **disable developer mode on production server**, but I want to retain this ability on developers computers.
I found a solution to disable it everywhere, but I need to identify the production server and disable developer mode only on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I delete the main button from the XML on the web interface.

It is best if you assign it to a group or individual.

In the Linux server go to `/opt/server/openerp/addons/web/stativc/src/xml/base.xml`

Find the line with `GREP -nr "developer"` and then open it with `vim base.xml`

Just go to the line that it shows, and erase it.