# (Odoo) How to hide the apps list and prevent user from accessing developer mode?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I want to create a group of which users can not see some apps/modules from the list and also can not access developer mode. How can I do this?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775664/odoo-how-to-completely-disable-developer-mode-on-production-server

Comment: This helped to deal with developer mode: https://www.programmersought.com/article/61886724404/